# How to create a JOB for Azure SQL?

Tags: azure-sql-database

I'm trying to create some jobs for our Azure servers (for sql databases).

I'm reading about it on the internet and tried to find some questiosn here with no success.

Theres a link saying I need to download something in the market place. I can't even find such app by looking for it.

Is there a way to create a job as we create on a SQL Server?

Comment: Please provide full information in questions, as it will help in getting useful, relevant, targetted, answers. Are you using Azure SQL "servers" or "managed instances"? *Theres a link saying ... something ...* what link and/or what is the something it says to download?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Azure SQL Servers rather than Managed Instances or on-prem instances in VMs<sup>†</sup>, and are trying to create SQL Agent jobs<sup>†</sup>, then you can not: SQL Agent Jobs are not supported for Azure SQL.

There are a number of ways to automate tasks in Azure SQL. The official way it is heading appears to be Elastic Database Jobs, though this feature is still officiall in preview.

See these links for a bit more detail:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-job-automation-overview
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/elastic-jobs-overview

<sub><sup>[†]</sup> If you are using managed or VM instances, or are looking to create some other form of job, edit your question accordingly.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Azure SQL Database does not support SQL Agent.

Depending what the job does, i.e. if it is calling a stored proc only then you can run it from an on-prem sql server agent job or SQL Managed Instance via Linked server.

1. Create a linked server on the on-prem
2. Create a job in the on-prem sql server which would call the SP in Azure.

Or you can Azure Automation : https://www.netwoven.com/2017/12/12/schedule-execution-sql-jobs-azure-automation-service/

Answer (score 2):

In bare Azure SQL Server it is not possible.
If you want to be as PaaS as possible, mentioned before options are very good:

- Elastic Jobs
- SQL Agent on Managed Instance
- Azure Automation

There are also other options:

- Azure Data Factory - as an orchestrator it can execute stored procedures and SQL code base on schedule or blob event
- Logic Apps - quite simple but powerful tool that have connectors for Azure SQL DB
- Power Automate (Flow) - quite similar to Logic Apps but available outside Azure, in Office offering and more non technical users friendly
- For hardcore cases you can implement in App Services, but that would be overkill

From my experience Azure Data Factory or Logic Apps are best options. Which one to use depends on triggering needs. ADF for more time based, and Logic Apps for event based are better.